# Storing Complex Formulas in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a RoR application that needs to calculate sales commissions for various companies. There will be new commission models after the application has gone live as new companies start using it. These commissions are typically represented as complex MS Excel formulas, but not always. I will need to reimplement these into Ruby.

As an example, a commission model may be the below lines **added together**:

```
column_1 * ( column_2 / column_3)
if ( column_6 > column_1 ) column_5 * column_4
if ( column_2 < column_1 ) column_2
```

Given that there will be new commission models after go live, what is the best way to store these in the database? (this part does not need to be overly user friendly, only developers will be adding new models)

Obviously this could be done using `eval` reading the above from the DB. Aside from the security concerns it doesn't feel like a "clean" solution.

How else can I tackle this?

I have been researching DSLs, using Excel files as black box calculators, formula gems and I'm struggling to find a nice way to do this.

TIA

Comment: Make a `Proc` object with a block containing the formula and serialize that `Proc` object.

Comment: I like your thought process but `Proc` objects aren't serialisable. `sourcify` might help until this is added into ruby-core. Looking into this now.

Comment: Not getting anywhere with this, adding layers of complexity. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Re: using excel files as black box calculators, I use [axlsx](http://axlsx.blogspot.com/2012/04/deeper-look-excel-reporting-in-ruby.html) for generating excel files in Ruby, and I think something like this might work for you:

```
require 'axlsx'
Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook do |wb|  
    wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row [column_1,column_2,column_3]
      sheet.add_row ["=A1*(B1/C1)"]
    end
  end
  p.serialize('results.xlsx')
end
```

However, since the formulas are actually executed by excel, You won't have access to them in code this way, only in the Excel output.

I know this is a month old question at this point, so I'm curious what you went with, if anything.

Comment: I haven't decided yet- I put it on the todo list as I haven't found a more "elegant" way of approaching this. I might end up having to use something list this. I don't need to create them programmatically fortunately (other than insert the inputs of course).

Comment: Haven't investigated this option further in terms of performance impacts, flexibility etc.